# Replicating a text box style with header

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox, text, box

I was looking a research paper on the ACM digital library and came across the following text box style on their website: [image]

See, for reference https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1016/j.csda.2006.11.002. I was wondering if it would be possible to recreate this style of text box in a LaTeX document. Existing styles of text box don't include this very unique style of header that has a small black rectangle on the left hand side.  Any help in recreating this would be very much appreciated, as I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can indeed be done with `tcolorbox`. It's not perfect, but the following example should give you something to start with. I made the little black rectangle with a simple `\rule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{textbox}[1]{
    sharp corners,
    boxsep=0mm,
    toptitle=2mm,
    lefttitle=0mm,
    colframe=black!3,
    colback=black!3,
    title={\rule[-2pt]{4.5pt}{10pt}\hspace*{1.5mm}#1},
    fonttitle=\bfseries\itshape\sffamily,
    coltitle=black,
    halign=flush left,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{textbox}{Abstract}
\lipsum[4]
\end{textbox}
\begin{textbox}{References}
\end{textbox}
\end{document}
```